# Overwrite the this value in array.prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, prototype, this

I've found that the native js sort function screws up from time to time so I wanted to implement my own. Lets say i have the following :

```
Array.prototype.customSort = function(sortFunction, updated) {...}
var array = [5, 2, 3, 6]
array.customSort(function(a,b) {return a - b})
console.log(array)
```

Array should be [2, 3, 5, 6]

Updated is the array that has been sorted.

No matter what I return in customSort, the order of array is still in the original order. How do I overwrite the 'this' value / get it to point to the array with the correct order?

Comment: What do you mean it screws up? `[5, 2, 3, 6].sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; })` works perfectly every time.

Comment: I didn't mean to say it screws up in that case. I have found instances where it does not sort correctly. I was trying to give a really simple example of what I would want a customSort function to return. I thought I was pretty clear on that point.

Comment: Why don't you give the actual example that fails instead?

Comment: Because I think you're trying to solve a problem you don't need to. I think you're using `sort` wrong. If you put up the _actual_ problem you're having with `sort` we can solve that so you don't need to screw with the prototype. It's called a XY issue. You're too busy focussing on solving Y when you should be solving X instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up iterating over the `updated` array and replacing each value in `this` with the value in `updated`. In code, that looks like...

```
function customSort(cb) {
    ...//updated is the sorted array that has been built
    var that = this;
    _.each(updated, function (ele, index) {
        that[index] = ele;
    })
}
```

I wanted the function to operate in the exact same way the native array.sort function does - it overwrites the array provided instead of returning a new, sorted array.

I find it odd that this works... you cannot overwrite the entire `this` value in one clean sweep but you can in steps. I couldn't do this for in the customSort function :

```
this = updated;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the actual code you gave above, you have to make sure that your `customSort` function updates `this`.

One case is that `customSort` only uses `this` as "read-only" input, that is - only puts the sorted array in `updated`, rather than changing `this`.
In such case, considering the code above (which you might have performed tests with), no `updated` parameter is sent to the function, to receive the sorted values.

Another case is that `customSort` returns the sorted array, in which case you have to collect it:

```
array = array.customSort(function(a,b) {return a - b});
console.log(array);
```